# How to get 'pinch to zoom'(mobile) effect using css or html(with greasemonkey)?

Tags: html, css

I want to enlarge the page on a drawing game garticphone.com(there is solo mode, to test code).

(Using EasyCanvas to share the pc screen with an ipad, I can pinch to zoom from ipad, the page is enlarged and there is no cursor issue offset on drawing area)

I tried with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and it did nothing.

With css on html{}:

using `transform: scale(1.15)` = no problem with cursor offset in top left corner, but problems in the other corners.

using `zoom: 1.15` = problem with cursor offset in all corners(the canvas cursor is in the top left corner but the actual cursor appears outside of canvas 50px(idk exactly) offset top left to the screen)

Answer (score 0):

These procedures can be used to create a "pinch to zoom" effect for a mobile website using CSS or HTML. Please be aware that depending on the structure and style of the website, this strategy may not be effective for all websites.

**1. Viewport Meta Tag:**

First, look in to see that your HTML document's  contains the appropriate viewport meta tag. By regulating the initial scale, this tag enables appropriate mobile responsiveness.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

**2. Transforming CSS:**

To scale the content, use CSS transform. However, this could lead to cursor offset issues, particularly in the corners. Use the following CSS to address these problems:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

/* Use this class to apply scaling */
.zoomed {
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

**3.JavaScript(Greasemonkey)**

JavaScript can be used to enable pinch-to-zoom capability in Greasemonkey. This is a simple script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Pinch to Zoom
// @namespace    http://yournamespace.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  Enable pinch-to-zoom on the website
// @include      http://yourwebsite.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        if (e.touches.length === 2) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const initialDistance = Math.hypot(e.touches[0].clientX - e.touches[1].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY - e.touches[1].clientY);
            const currentDistance = Math.hypot(e.touches[0].clientX - e.touches[1].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY - e.touches[1].clientY);

            const scaleFactor = currentDistance / initialDistance;
            document.body.style.transform = `scale(${scaleFactor})`;
        }
    });
})();
```

Make the @include URL consistent with the URL of your website.

Pinch-to-zoom feature should be available while using Greasemonkey to access the website thanks to this JavaScript code. Be sure to customize it to your unique use case and website architecture. Just keep in mind that depending on the site's architecture and event handling, not every website may operate flawlessly with this method.